# JsonApiDotNetCore 4.0 has removed BuildResourceGraph from JsonApiOptions. What is the replacement?

Tags: asp.net-core, json-api, asp.net-core-3.1

I am migrating from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1. In doing so, I have updated the JsonApiDotNetCore package from 3.1 to 4.0.0 alpha 4.

In 2.2, I used JsonApiDotNetCore 3.1 and was using BuildResourceGraph to add any JSON API resources to the resource graph. Code below:

```
IMvcCoreBuilder objMvcCoreBuilder = null;

objServices.AddJsonApi((objOptions) =>
{
    objOptions.BuildResourceGraph((objBuilder) =>
    {
        objBuilder
        .AddResource<Register>("registers")
        .AddResource<Client>("clients")   
        ;
    });
}, objMvcCoreBuilder);
```

But, I get the following error:

> 'JsonApiOptions' does not contain a definition for
>   'BuildResourceGraph' and no accessible extension method
>   'BuildResourceGraph' accepting a first argument of type
>   'JsonApiOptions' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

What is the replacement for BuildResourceGraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the `JsonApiOptions.cs` commit history on Git, I found the change:

```
IMvcCoreBuilder objMvcCoreBuilder = null;

objServices.AddJsonApi(
    options => options.Namespace = "api/v1",
    resources: resources =>
                resources
                .AddResource<Register>("registers")
                .AddResource<Client>("clients")             
                ,
    mvcBuilder: objMvcCoreBuilder
);
```

Go down to the `/NoEntityFrameworkExample/Startup.cs` file and you will see the diff that shows the change. Other than that, there is only a cryptic mention to renaming BuildResourceManager in the change log notes at the top of the site.

https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore/commit/7b8250bf5b9e64b91d8fa0357e915a1121eb6081#diff-d56ca61ff20d8be0b7cb20c9fd106d9f

The revised version of the file is here:

https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore/blob/7b8250bf5b9e64b91d8fa0357e915a1121eb6081/src/Examples/NoEntityFrameworkExample/Startup.cs